# Can I receive calls only from a set of approved phone numbers?

Tags: iphone, security, call

How can I receive calls only from a set of approved phone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

One way you *could* do this is to use the iPhone's Do Not Disturb feature.

More specifically:

1. Launch Settings
2. Tap on Do Not Disturb
3. Enable the **Manual** option at the top
4. Tap on the *Allow Calls From* field
5. Select the *group*<sup>1</sup>of people you want to receive calls from
6. Go back to the previous screen
7. Tap on the *Always* option near the bottom of the screen
8. Exit Settings

<sup>1</sup> You may need to create a particular group for the people you want to allow calls from. To do this you will need to use your computer or a 3rd party app. Another option would be to ensure you don't have anyone in your contacts who you don't want to receive calls from. In this case you would then select *All Contacts* as the Group at Step 5.